# Can you perform a Wick rotation if the poles are on the imaginary axis?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, regularization, wick-rotation, analyticity

I know you can perform a [Wick rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wick_rotation) whenever the poles are outside the contour but what happens if the poles are on the imaginary axis? Can you do it anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the lore is that one is supposed to regularize an oscillatory Minkowski integral from a QFT calculation by the Feynman $i\epsilon$-prescription (which moves poles off the integration contour) in order to Wick rotate to an exponentially decaying and convergent Euclidean integral. If one encounters poles at the Euclidean end of the Wick rotation, then something has likely gone wrong in the process.